# Elasticsearch geo distance query exclude water bodies

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

I am working on Elasticsearch and I have a use case where I have to list apartments within 20 miles from me. 
Here is the query I am using:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "20mi",
            "distance_type": "plane",
            "location": {
              "lon": -122.4194,
              "lat": 37.7749
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this query does not exclude water bodies and other inaccessible geography. Does elasticsearch exclude them under the query or is there a specific way to do it?

Comment: In what sense do you want them excluded? Do you want to actually calculate the shortest driving distance to your point and use that for your calculation instead?

Comment: how do you have apartments in water bodies or inaccessible geography ?

Comment: Elastic doesnot know geo context, if you need one, use googleMaps (or other) when you index your docs to add some geo context info (water, ocean, nuclear area...)